# Override 404 page for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a database of hundreds urls which we want to show similar content for.  But we don't want to make hundreds pages for in wordpress.

Is there a way I can override/suppress wordpress 404 page to show the content from a page (already created) on all url in this database.

All I need is the code to do this to one URL and I'll be-able to do the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the theme folder use `404.php`

This way you could find the URL that was called and customize the page a little.

Hope this helps,
Jason

**[Update]**

I don't see why a plugin is needed. In the 404.php template you would have something like so:

```
<?php 

get_header();


//Get called URL 
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//Some function to check database to see if this URL should exist
if(checkIfPageExists($url)) {
   //Page Code Here
} else {
   //404 Code Here
}


get_footer();

?>
```

**[Update 2]**

Fixing the status code is easy:

```
<?php 

//Get called URL 
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//Some function to check database to see if this URL should exist
if(checkIfPageExists($url)) {
   //Set 200 Status
   status_header( "200" );
   //Get Header
   get_header();
   //Page Code Here
} else {
   //Set 404 Status
   status_header( "404" );
   //Get Header
   get_header();
   //404 Code Here
}


get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: I'm need to create a plugin  so I need to hook into WordPress somewhere.

Comment: The problem with this is that it will still return a 404 status.  Which may not be what's wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htaccess. Enter the following at the top of the htaccess file in your wordpress installation. 404page.html is the error page you created.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 301 redirect in your htaccess file

`RewriteRule ^your-db-url.html /your-redirect-page.html [L,R=301]`

You may also be able to write a script that could list out all of your urls in this format and copy and paste this into your .htaccess file above your wordpress rewrite rules.